# Error: Access restriction: The type 'DataSource' is not API (restriction on required library ..\rt.jar)

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, jdbc

I'm trying to understand how to work with Spring JDBC framework.

I've found example on http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_jdbc_example.htm and trying to implement in my own project.

This is my example

```
package test;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

public class TestJDBCTemplate {
       private DataSource dataSource;
       private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateObject;

       public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
          this.dataSource = dataSource;
          this.jdbcTemplateObject = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
       }

}
```

But I got the problem with

```
import javax.sql.DataSource
```

Access restriction: The type 'DataSource' is not API (restriction on required library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_31\lib\rt.jar')

What's wrong with this import and how to fix it.
This kind of import I've seen in all examples about Spring JDBC framework.

Comment: Which database are you using.?

Comment: Postgresql 9.1.6. But I think it doesn't matter in this context...

Comment: You seem to be using JDBC in a project that is meant to run in a restricted environment (android app? Google app engine?) where JDBC can't be used.

Comment: It's simple desctop application example.. The problem solved in answer below. Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to build path settings of your project in eclipse. Remove JRE system library. Add it again. This should resolve your error.

Comment: Thank you Sezin. It works. Can you explain me the root of this problem? Some kind of bug in Java?

Comment: You're welcome. Probably there are more than DataSource in you jars. When you remove and add you override others and accept JRE's.

Comment: If it's stupid, but it works - it is not stupid :) tnx man!